# php based crawler/scraper for the page loaded with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, api, curl, web-scraping

I just working on a script that loads html page of an ecommerce site. My script fine but this is enable to provide me html added by jquery on the page.

Is there any way to resolve this?

I am using below code:-

Currently I am using meta tags for fetching data.

```
$url = "https://www.flipkart.com/pureit-classic-23-l-gravity-based-water-purifier/p/itmefqycwh7mgwan?pid=WAPEFQY5YEWY4ZGT&srno=s_1_5&otracker=search&lid=LSTWAPEFQY5YEWY4ZGTO514UM&qH=d5e3b0f34459bd7d";

$response = getPriceFromFlipkart($url);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($response);
echo '</pre>';
/* Returns the response in JSON format */

function getPriceFromFlipkart($url) {

    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 10.10; labnol;) ctrlq.org");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $html = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    $regexTitle = '/<meta name="og_title" property="og:title" content="([^"]*)"/';
    preg_match($regexTitle, $html, $title);
    $regexDesc = '/<meta name="Description" content="([^"]*)"/';
    preg_match($regexDesc, $html, $desc);
    $price = get_string_between($desc[1], 'Rs.', 'from');

    if ($price && $title) {
        $response = array("price" => "Rs. $price.00", "title" => $title[1], "Description" => $desc[1]);
    } else {
        $response = array("status" => "404", "error" => "We could not find the product details on Flipkart $url");
    }
    return $response;
}

function get_string_between($string, $start, $end) {
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0)
        return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return trim(substr($string, $ini, $len));
}
```

Comment: You are not a browser, so you cannot run the javascript, so you will never see what the javascript result are

Comment: you are right, I am getting only dom data but not the data added by jquery on the page. Is there any way?

Comment: Use something like [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) or [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) which will fetch pages, render them internally, and evaluate any Javascript on the pages.  You can also write code with those to interact with the DOM after the page has loaded.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, Can you please provide me some working example?